wifi access in 24.04
i am trying to get access to my WIFI in ubuntu for completing an assignment at my college.
However it doesn't show at the tool bar and i don't know what to configure that it will show up.
thanks for those who will help me for that.

What is the exact WiFi card or chip set you have? You need the right driver for it.

i have the intel Wi-Fi6 AX201 160 MHz . So which driver do you recommend me to install?
